# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null When I try to read a number from a .txt

Tags: java, null, numbers

```
try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Encuestas/Encuesta_"+s+".txt"));
        try {
            this.id = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());
            this.genero = in.readLine();
            this.fecha = in.readLine();
            this.n_preguntas = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());
            for(int i = 0; i < this.n_preguntas; ++i){
                Integer tip = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());
                String aux = "";

                aux = in.readLine();
```

When I try to read Integer tip = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine()); it doesn't work and I don't understand why... I do the same before and it is working.
This is the error:

```
5. Leer encuestajava.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
at prop.dominio.Encuesta.leer(Encuesta.java:134)
at prop.dominio.driver_encuesta.main(driver_encuesta.java:219)
```

Comment: check your file path first and file is assigned to BufferedReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply check like this,

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.n_preguntas; ++i){   
    String line = null;
    if((line = in.readLine()) != null){
        Integer tip = Integer.valueOf(line);
        String aux = "";
    }
```

If there is only ten lines in the file, when your reading 11th line you got this error

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.valueof()` throws a NullPointerException if the value you are passing to it is null. Check that the first line of your file is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message reports "null" there is no malformed input, but none (empty line). It it safe to first read the String value and test it against null, e.g.:

```
String intStr = in.readLine();

if(intStr != null) {
    int i = Integer.valueOf(intStr);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Empty line");
}
```

Or surround the parsing code with a try-catch which also will help to detect read Strings not convertable into integer numbers.